# Enable touch events in a webview (UWP)

Tags: c#, windows, webview, uwp, touch-event

I need to enable touch events in a webview in an UWP-app (Universal Windows Platform).

It is possible to set this flag in the local installed edge browser: Type "about:flags" in the edge browser and move to "Touch events". Default it is set to "Always off".

Can i set this flag programmatically in a webview instance in my UWP-app?

Background: I need all touch events in a website to pan a digital map.

Let me know if you need more information.

Webview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, as indicated in the Events table, `WebView` doesn’t support most of the user input events inherited from `UIElement`, such as `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, and `PointerPressed`. Details please reference the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Remarks) of the `WebView` class. And the relative team is working on [enable Manipulation Events for WebView](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/15260955-enable-manipulation-events-for-webview) that you may vote that.

As the remarks mentioned, a common workaround is to use `InvokeScriptAsync` with the JavaScript eval function to use the HTML event handlers, and to use `window.external.notify` from the HTML event handler to notify the application using `WebView.ScriptNotify`. In another words, you may try to capture the touch events inside the website by JavaScript and notify the `WebView`. For details about how do to please reference the [WebView official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlWebView).